# Append parameter to URL address not work in multiple function (second function not change)

Tags: javascript

I try to change url in my website with javascript. First function (degis) ischanging url. after run degis function, I want to run listele function to change url adress. (add parameter) but second function is not changinglink. I can get alert message from second code. What should I do? thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var q=0;
function degis(src){

    q= src.value;
    window.location = '/cgi-bin/koha/tools/dev_yetki.pl?q='+q;
    alert("1");
}
function listele(){
        var x=document.getElementById("yeniden");
        var y= x.value;
alert(y);
        var url = window.location.href;
         if (url.indexOf('?') > -1){
               url += '&y='+y
         }else{
               url += '?q='+q
         }
         window.location.href = url;
 }
```

Comment: When you call the first function (`degis`), the page is **reloaded**. So all your JS state (variables such as `q`) is lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use window.location.replace(url) or window.location.reload(url) instead of window.location.href = url;

Answer (score 1):

Missing `q` in `url += '?q='+q` statement in the second function.  Try this:

```
function listele(src){
    q= src.value;

    var x=document.getElementById("yeniden");
    var y= x.value;

    var url = window.location.href;
     if (url.indexOf('?') > -1){
           url += '&y='+y
     }else{
           url += '?q='+q
     }
     window.location = url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling `degis`. Add `degis()` wherever you want the url to change.